# App crashes after exiting Mail Composer

Tags: email, uiwebview, crash, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My app is crashing shortly after closing a MFMailComposeViewController.  A UIWebDocumentView is releasing, which deallocates a ComposeBodyField object and it crashes on objc_msgSend.  It only happens some of the time, and only on old devices. I'm assuming that something is being release/cleaned up before it's supposed to, so when the message is sent, the object doesn't exist.

The problem is that I can't get anymore information than that, and I have no idea how any of it ties together.  If anyone can shine some light on this, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with crashing after dimissing the MFMailComposer. After removing the [myMailComposer release] everything is fine. I'm sure I'm following the rules for memory management since it's fine all over in the app except at this specific place. Now my "Build & Analyze" nags about it, but the app is perfectly stable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code that works for me.

```
 - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error

{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
    {
        break;
    }
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
    {
        break;
    }
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
    {


        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Email Sent" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backHome" sender: self]; 

        break;
    }
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
    {
       NSLog(@" Failed");
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Email Failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];


    }
        break;
}
}
```